# C++ Qt QGraphicsWidget background

Tags: c++, qt, 2d

I'm making simple 2D game (maze) and I am using QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsGridLayout to manage tiles into grid.

Map is represented by string (# is wall, . is empty field...).

So I'm going through this string, creating labels with pixmap and inserting them into grid layout:

```
QLabel *label;    
QGraphicsProxyWidget *widget;
...
for (..) {
  for (..) {
     label = new QLabel();
     label->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/new/images/img/w.png"));
     widget = scene->addWidget(label);
     layout->addItem(widget, i, j);
  }
}
```

where scene is QGraphicsScene and layout is QGraphicsGridLayout. It works fine but I have problems with transparent background of pixmaps. Each pixmap consists of some shape and transparent backgroud. When I try to display label on main widget (QDialog window), everything is ok. But after inserting into the scene, its background is grey.

I tried it without grid layer (only graphicsview and scene) but result was same.

Is there any way to set background of scene's items transparent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the stylesheet of the label to have transparent background and no border:

```
label->setStyleSheet("background: transparent; border: none");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly. I have a one more question - is there a way how to resize window (QDialog) so the QGraphicsView doesn't need to have scrollbars? I have window with some buttons etc. and QGraphicsView with rectangle in scene.

Comment: You can reimplement resizeEvent( QResizeEvent *event ) in your QGraphicsView. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23153365/qgraphicsview-scale-with-windowsize/23153512#23153512